# Why does Git merge appear to create multiple commits on the target branch for non-fast-forward commits?

Tags: git, merge

I have a repo that looks like this:

```
  * 68789440 - (origin/task1, task1) task1 commit 5
  * 8ed9a8ed - task1 commit 4
  * 35946846 - task1 commit 3
  * c825cc00 - task1 commit 2
  * c4f84460 - task1 commit 1
* | 6f0f067e - (HEAD -> main, origin/main) main commit 1
|/
*   4e5e407d - common ancestor on main
```

I merged from task1 to main, without the --squash flag:

```
> git merge task1

*   946f648d - (HEAD -> main) merged from branch 'task1'
|\
| * 68789440 - (origin/task1, task1) task1 commit 5
| * 8ed9a8ed - task1 commit 4
| * 35946846 - task1 commit 3
| * c825cc00 - task1 commit 2
| * c4f84460 - task1 commit 1
* | 6f0f067e - (origin/main) main commit 1
|/
*   4e5e407d - common ancestor on main
```

Why do all of the commits on the task1 branch appear to be applied on main?

```
> git status
On branch main
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/main' by 6 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

I verified that the 6 commits are the merge commit plus the ones on the task branch (using git rebase -i). There's some subtlety around merging/squashing that I don't grok. Help!

Part of my befuddlement comes from the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge):

> Then "git merge task1" will replay the changes made on the topic branch since it diverged from master until its current commit on top of master, and record the result in **a new commit** along with the names of the two parent commits and a log message from the user describing the changes.

I read that to mean a single commit, not a rewriting of the task branch's history onto main.

Answer (score 0):

No, that's not how it works. When you merge (without any tricks) git will *join* the changes applied on the separarte branches and the resulting revision will have 2 parent revisions, just like what you see there.  If you ask to squash then a single revision will show up on top of the revision you were before running the merge and it won't have multiple parents.... actually git won't even know that the branches were merged.

Answer (score 0):

You are misreading the graph. 946f648d is a merge commit with two parents — that's what a simple merge is.

- The first parent, i.e. the previous commit on `main`, is 6f0f067e
- The second parent, i.e. the branch that got merged in, starts at 68789440 and is clearly labeled `task1`.

The merge commit combines those two commits so that the changes from both branches are now incorporated into `main`. Usually at this point you will delete `task1` because it is just a name; the history topology is clearly shown by the split at 4e5e407d and the join at the merge commit.

You are also misreading the docs. What happened is exactly what the docs said would happen. The changes from `main` and `task1` since 4e5e407d were applied on top of 6f0f067e (the previous end of `main`), and the result was committed as the merge commit (still on `main`), recording the parents so that the graph is maintained.

So basically what you are doing and seeing is a basic merge and the results are exactly as expected.